# AWS Lambda, Python : Call Shell script from Lambda or Linux command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am working on an AWS Lambda script written in Python where I am currently getting all the instances with specific tags, and removing the oldest one from them. After that, from the remaining instances, I would like to call a linux command on the instances. The only thing I require is to call `crontab -r` , as the oldest instance will have the cron set, and adding those crons in the ASG generated instances will cause duplicate emails being sent.

I am done till the part of getting all the instances except the oldest one, but how can I call `crontab -r` on each of those instances? Any ideas. Thank you.

Code :

```
import boto.ec2
import boto3
conn=boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-central-1")
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
instances_list = []
process_instance_list = []
for res in reservations:
    for inst in res.instances:
        if 'Name' in inst.tags:
            if inst.tags['Name'] == 'PROJECT_NAME' :
               instances_list.append(inst);


instances_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.launch_time, reverse=False)
non_processed_id=instances_list[0]

for val in instances_list:
    if val.id != non_processed_id.id:
       // Call crontab -r here.
```

Thank you. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143310/aws-lambda-run-command-on-ec2-instance-and-get-result

Comment: Ideally use EC2 Run Command via boto3. Or use Paramiko.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [boto3 send_command](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) to execute a command on ec2.

Example for your case:

```
boto3.client('ssm').send_command(
    InstanceIds=[val.id], 
    DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', 
    Parameters={'commands': ['crontab -r']}, 
    Comment='Crontab remove'
)
```